# how to emit short xml tag in Clojure?

Tags: xml, clojure

You can create an XML element with `clojure.data.xml`:

```
(clojure.data.xml/emit-str (clojure.data.xml/element :test))
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><test></test>"
```

I don't know how to create a short element of the form `<test/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way of doing it without `element` fn, from the [tests](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/data/xml/test_emit.clj#L228) provided in `clojure.data.xml`.

```
(emit-str {:tag :test :content []})
;=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><test/>"

(emit-str {:tag :test :content [""]})
;=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><test></test>"
```

Comment: What version are you using? I can't reproduce it with [org.clojure/data.xml "0.2.0-alpha2"]. There is also this ticket: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/DXML-25

Comment: I guess it is based on an older version. I couldn't test it. You might try older version or monitor library change. Good luck!

Comment: I had to use the latest `[org.clojure/data.xml "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701923/how-to-load-latest-clojure-lib-from-git-repository