# how to load latest Clojure lib from git repository

Tags: clojure, dependency-management, leiningen

I'd like to use the latest development version of `clojure.data.xml`. I'm using Leiningen to manage dependencies. However, there is no SNAPSHOT version in the repository on [Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.clojure%22%20AND%20a%3A%22data.xml%22). How can I easily load the latest version from GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Maven Central repository does not hold snapshots. To use snapshots of the Clojure projects, you need to add the snapshot repository to your project. Full details here: http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Maven+Settings+and+Repositories

The key line to add to a Leiningen project is:

```
:repositories {"sonatype-oss-public" "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"}
```

The latest snapshot dependency version for data.xml is:

```
[org.clojure/data.xml "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]
```

All Clojure contrib projects are built and released as a snapshot on every commit (gathered in 1 hr polls) AND once a week regardless of commits. So, pulling a snapshot will generally be the same or nearly the same as what's on github.

Comment: I totally didn't expect this, since Leiningen lists only Maven Central and Clojars: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#repositories

Comment: Yeah, that's all correct, just doesn't cover Maven Central snapshots. Release and snapshot repos are often separated. And usually, you don't need to use Clojure and Clojure contrib library snapshots. I'm sure you could submit an edit on that page though.

Comment: I did submit a PR to them regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the latest version from GitHub would be to press the green button at https://github.com/clojure/data.xml and then the 'copy to clipboard' button that will appear next. Then get a terminal on your machine and go `git clone <pasted here>`. You will now have that repository locally.

From there if you wanted to use that development version from another lein project you could type `lein install` from the command line. If that still didn't give you a great workflow please read http://jakemccrary.com/blog/2012/03/28/working-on-multiple-clojure-projects-at-once/.